Question on a proof of the zeros theorem
The book states the definition of the zeros theorem:
Every polynomial of degree $n\geq1$ has exactly $n$ zeros, provided that a zero of multiplicity $k$ is counted $k$ times. 
Proof $\ $ Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. By the Complete Factorization Theorem
$$P(x) = a(x-c_1)(x-c_2)\cdots(x-c_n)$$
Now suppose that c is any given zero of $P$. Then
$$P(c) = a(c - c_1)(c-c_2)\cdots(c-c_2) = 0$$
Thus by the Zero-Product Property, one of the factors $c - c_i$ must be 0, so $c = c_i$ for some $i$. It follows that $P$ has exactly the $n$ zeros $c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_n$. 
I didn't quite understand how the last statement is true, why does it "follows that P has exactly the n zeros c1, c2, ..., cn"?

Context matters.  $x^2+1$ has no real zeroes at all, for example.  But, assuming you are working over the complex numbers or something like that, then the given argument shows that $P(c)=0$ implies that $c$ must be one the $c_i$.  And we already know the $c_i$ are all zeroes.

The last statement is a result of the fact that the complex numbers are a field, and as a result the equation $ab = 0$ only has the solutions $a = 0$ and $b = 0$.
From that, we can claim that $P(c) = 0$ if and only if $c$ belongs to the set $\{c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n\}$, i.e. $P$ has exactly the given $n$ zeros. In one direction, we can see that if $c = c_i$ for some $i$ then $(c - c_i) = 0$ and so $P(c) = 0$. In the other direction, if $P(c) = 0$ then we must have that either $c - c_1 = 0$, or $c - c_2 = 0$, etc.
Or to look at it another way, suppose $c$ is not equal to any of the $c_i$. Then $c - c_i \neq 0$, meaning that $(c - c_1)(c - c_2)\ldots(c - c_n)$ is the product of $n$ non-zero values, and thus must also be non-zero, which means that $P(c) \neq 0$.
